# CrystalReports adding top 3 qty

Tags: crystal-reports

I am designing a crystal report .

report output contains conum,item,qty

the report is group by item and there is running total field of qty on Item grouping.

i want to add the top 3 item total qty.

how i can do this in crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Top 3 quantities:

If the report is set out as above with a group on item and a summary on quantity per item then you can use the "Group Sort Expert".

Select "Top N" from the first box.  Choose based on ="Sum of quantity".  Set N=3 and remove the "others" option.

This will display the top 3 items by sum of quantity.